# How can I find a tag in html site that I know it matches a certain pattern in python?

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to get the width percentage from the winter/spring/summer etc charts in this site:
https://www.fragrantica.com/perfume/Christian-Dior/Sauvage-Eau-de-Parfum-48100.html

For example, for the winter season, I want to find this row in the page elements:

```
<div style="border-radius: 0.2rem; height: 0.3rem; background: rgb(120, 214, 240); width: 90.3491%; opacity: 1;"></div>
```

I have tried the following

```
res = requests.get("https://www.fragrantica.com/perfume/Christian-Dior/Sauvage-Eau-de-Parfum- 
                    48100.html", headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) 
                                           AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko),
                                           Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'}
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
winter_row = soup.select('div[style="rgb(120, 214, 240)"]')
print(winter_row)
```

I wanted to find that certain html row using the RGB that is unique for each season. The problem is I get an empty list as the output. I want my code to extract the width for each season, day and night from the charts so I know exactly what percentage the votes are.

Do you guys have any idea what should I do?

PS:
I also got the name of the perfume from the site and it works, so I know I get a response.

```
name_row = soup.select('#toptop')[0]
name = name_row.getText().replace('\n', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You get an empty list because you use:

`soup.select('div[style="rgb(120, 214, 240)"]')`

But this expression is looking for an exact match.

But in fact you want to find `div` elements having a `style` attribute, and this attribute must contain a `background` CSS property with a specific value (`rgb(120, 214, 240)` in your example).
So you have to use this *CSS attribute selector* syntax:

```
soup.select("[style*='background: rgb(120, 214, 240)']")
```

Example:

```
htmlpage = """<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="border-radius: 0.2rem; height: 0.3rem; background: rgb(120, 214, 240); width: 90.3491%; opacity: 1;"></div>
  </body>
</html>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlpage, 'html.parser')
extracted = soup.select("[style*='background: rgb(120, 214, 240)']")

print(extracted)
```

Output:

```
[<div style="border-radius: 0.2rem; height: 0.3rem; background: rgb(120, 214, 240); width: 90.3491%; opacity: 1;"></div>]
```

And you should use `res.text` instead of `res.content` which gives you the content of the response in bytes, not as text that can be parsed.

Comment: I still get an empty list :(